# For each item entered in column A, check that the equivalent of "A" to "G" is entered in column AT?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check for each item in column A (Position) whether one of the values A to G is assigned to column AT (Size), otherwise it give an error.(The number of articles isn't constant).
this code does not work:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet")

Row = 10

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet").Cells(zeile, 1).Value <> ""

 If Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "A" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "B" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "C" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "D" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "E" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "F" Or Sheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(Row, 46).Value = "G" Then
  Row = Row + 1
   Exit Do
    Else
    MsgBox ("fill Größenlauf ")
    End If
Loop
End With
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Select Case` is useful when checking for one of multiple values.

Try this:

```vb
Dim rw As Long

rw = 10
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet")
    Do While Len(.Cells(rw, "A").Value) > 0
        Select Case .Cells(rw, "AT").Value
            Case "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"
                'OK
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Fill Größenlauf on row# " & rw
                Exit Do
        End Select
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: `Select Case` will be helpful for the apparent beginner Kimia; posted a similar idea using arrays via a `Like "[ABCDEFG]"` operator +:)

Comment: `Like` is also a good approach (and a bit less typing...)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your post you want to

- check the **validity of character inputs** (starting in cell `AT11`)
- by giving an error notice if the cell values don't equal characters `"A" to "G"` (which of course excludes empty cells or other values).

**Some hints to frequent issues**

- Looping through a range by means of VBA can be time consuming, it's faster to use arrays (see section b and c).
- It's faster to calculate the last row (c.f. section a) than to check each row separately via `Do Until ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet").Cells(zeile, 1).Value <> ""`, where btw you forgot to change **`zeile`** to the variable name `Row`. - Note that it's *no* good coding practice to shadow existing property names like **`Row`** with an identical variable name *(so you could use `r` instead for instance)*.
- Instead of checking all character occurrencies separately, I demonstrate a use via the `Like` operator (c.f. section d) via `If Not data(i, 1) Like "[ABCDEFG]" Then`. ~~> Of course you might use a `Select Case` structure, too as shown some minutes before by @TimWilliams.
- The logic in your original code example stops the row loop with the first finding of a invalid or empty character wheras I demonstrate how to get all found cells.
- All notices get assigned to the 1-dim array `missing`, get redimmed to the actual count of invalid cells and shown by joining all findings.
- Furthermore `Sheets(ActiveSheet)` is no valid code, think you wanted say `Sheets("Ordersheet")` or even better ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet")`in order to fully qualify your sheet or range reference. If you actually want to use the currently active sheet it suffices to use simply`ActiveSheet`.

```
Option Explicit                ' force variable declarations in code module head

Sub checkValidity()
Const StartRow As Long = 2     ' define fixed start row of data to be checked
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ordersheet")
'a) get last row
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'b) get 1-based 2-dimensional datafield array
    Dim data As Variant
    data = .Range("AT1:AT" & lastRow)
End With
'c) provide for sufficient elements in a "flat" 1-dim array named missing
    Dim missing() As String
    ReDim missing(1 To UBound(data))
'd) show invalid data in VB Editor's immediate window

    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = StartRow To UBound(data)            ' start check at row 11!
        If Not data(i, 1) Like "[ABCDEFG]" Then ' don't accept characters other than A..G
            ii = ii + 1                         ' increment counter for missing elements
            missing(ii) = "AT" & i              ' remember cell address, e.g. AT11
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve missing(1 To ii)             ' resize to actually found elements
    
    Debug.Print "Missing entries in the following cells:" & vbNewLine & _
                Join(missing, ", ")
    'alternatively:
    'MsgBox "Missing entries in cells" & vbNewLine & Join(missing, ", "), vbExclamation, "Invalid entries"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for your Time and Help ;)